# DirectX Blending State issue

Tags: c++, directx, blending

I've got an issue i failed to solve, so i seek your help.
I'm developing a DirectX App, in which my scene contains a page with text on it and i'm trying to add higlighting logic.

So i want to be able to highlight a text and also to change this highlighting's color \ opacity.

In order to do so, i'm trying to use ID3D11BlendState. Please consider a little code snippet on how i create it:

```
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        D3D11_BLEND_DESC blendDesc;
        D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC rtBlend;
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11BlendState> state;
        auto d3dDev = this->dxDevMt.GetD3DDevice();

        rtBlend.BlendEnable = TRUE;
        rtBlend.SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_DEST_COLOR;
        rtBlend.DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
        rtBlend.BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
        rtBlend.SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
        rtBlend.DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
        rtBlend.BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
        rtBlend.RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

        blendDesc.AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;
        blendDesc.IndependentBlendEnable = FALSE;

        for (auto &i : blendDesc.RenderTarget) {
            i = rtBlend;
        }

        hr = d3dDev->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, state.GetAddressOf());
```

The problem is, - it is not working in a way i want it to work. 
As long as alpha equals 1 it looks just fine:

[image: As long as alpha equals 1 it looks just fine:]
But if i try to change it somewhat, - any color that was before changes into black:[image: But i try to change it somewhat, - any color that was before changes into black]
I don't really understand why is this happening and i ask for your guidance!.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you rendering a plain colored rectangle over formerly rendered text? Or does the rectangle use a texture with the text? What exactly did you changed, when all turned black? Which values did you use before and after?

Comment: I'm redering highlight using d3d. i'm creating buffers, shaders and so on

i change alpha values on highlight color

so it was 0 1 0 1
then 0 1 0 0.9

Comment: That blend state looks weird. Are you sure this is what you want? Usually, you use  `SRC_ALPHA` and `INV_SRC_ALPHA` for source and destination blend.

Comment: @NicoSchertler well, the thing is, i want black letters to be on top of my highlight. 

what you have suggested just won't cut it.

Comment: Ah, you're multiplying the highlight on top of the text. I can't explain why the color turns grey. But I'm pretty sure that you won't get a single-pass solution that also uses alpha. Can't you just draw the highlight underneath the text and use usual alpha blending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got it working.
In case anyone would ever struggle with this kind of issue, try doing this:

Firstly, pass your highlight color into pixel shader. Then you want do treat this color's alpha value as a lerp value between white color (page background) and your value.

so your shader would look presumably something like:

```
cbuffer Buf0 : register(b0){
    float4 Color;
}

struct PsInput{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
};

float4 main(PsInput input) : SV_TARGET{
    float4 color2 = lerp(float4(1,1,1,1), Color, Color.a);
    return color2;
}
```

and after that you want to set your blendstate to multiply colors:

```
rtBlend.BlendEnable = TRUE;
rtBlend.SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_DEST_COLOR;
rtBlend.DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
rtBlend.BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
rtBlend.SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;// D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
rtBlend.DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;// D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
rtBlend.BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
rtBlend.RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

blendDesc.AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;
blendDesc.IndependentBlendEnable = FALSE;
```